# MDX limit usage

Tags: mdx, pentaho

Lets say after a basic query in MDX my output was 100 rows. If I want to limit to top 10 rows, I can use topcount. But, this usage of Topcount will fetch entire 100 rows from database and then pick the top 10 from it.

I wonder if there is any other possible way to fetch top ten rows directly from database?